# How to load image into ImageView and override onLoadFailed() only?

Tags: android, android-glide

So I'm trying to migrate to Glide v4 but I'm not able to figure out how to do the following:

```
Glide.with(holder.icon.getContext())
                .load(imageUrl)
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .centerCrop()
                .into(new GlideDrawableImageViewTarget(holder.icon) {


                    @Override
                    public void onLoadFailed(Exception e, Drawable errorDrawable) {
                        super.onLoadFailed(e, errorDrawable);
                        Glide.clear(holder.icon);
                        holder.icon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }

                });
```

The closes I've come is by using `ImageViewTarget` but then I have to override `setResource()` which seems unnecessary when all I want to do is to handle the case when image loading fails.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

> In Glide v3, options were handled individually by a series of complicated multityped builders. In Glide v4 these have been replaced by a single builder with a single type and a series of options objects that can be provided to the builder

Glide V4 has changed the implementation of what you are doing using Glide V3, [Glide v4 docs](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/migrating.html)

explains how to achieve the same thing using the new implementation.

Comment: Thanks. I've read through the docs but I'm still not sure I understand what I have to do to accomplish what I want.

Comment: This is an example of how to use Glide 4 to load an image [http://devdeeds.com/android-tutorial-glide-v4-implementation/]